# RabbitMQ Grafana community dashboard fails to load into Grafana on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to add an observability stack to my kubernetes environment which is currently running RabbitMQ from the official [RabbitMQ Operator](https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator). I have installed the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
KUBE_PROMETHEUS_STACK_VERSION='45.7.1'
KUBE_PROMETHEUS_STACK_NAME='prom'
KUBE_PROMETHEUS_STACK_NAMESPACE='kube-prometheus'
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo update
helm upgrade "$KUBE_PROMETHEUS_STACK_NAME" prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack \
  --version "$KUBE_PROMETHEUS_STACK_VERSION" \
  --install \
  --namespace "$KUBE_PROMETHEUS_STACK_NAMESPACE" \
  --create-namespace \
  --wait \
  --set "defaultRules.create=false" \
  --set "nodeExporter.enabled=false" \
  --set "prometheus.prometheusSpec.ruleSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false" \
  --set "prometheus.prometheusSpec.podMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false" \
  --set "prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false" \
  --set "prometheus.prometheusSpec.probeSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false" \
  --set "alertmanager.alertmanagerSpec.useExistingSecret=true" \
  --set "grafana.env.GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=flant-statusmap-panel"
```

I've added the service monitor using the following yaml and can see the metrics in prometheus:

```
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: kube-prometheus
  # If labels are defined in spec.serviceMonitorSelector.matchLabels of your deployed Prometheus object, make sure to include them here.
  labels:
    release: prom
spec:
  endpoints:
  - port: prometheus
    scheme: http
    interval: 15s
    scrapeTimeout: 14s
  - port: prometheus-tls
    scheme: https
    interval: 15s
    scrapeTimeout: 14s
    tlsConfig:
      insecureSkipVerify: true # set to false and uncomment lines below to enable tls verification
        # ca:
        #   secret:
        #     key: ca.crt
        #     name: tls-secret # name of the secret containing the CA cert which signed the RabbitMQ Prometheus TLS cert
        # serverName: '*.RABBITMQ-INSTANCE-NAME.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local'
  - port: prometheus
    scheme: http
    path: /metrics/detailed
    params:
      family:
        - queue_coarse_metrics
        - queue_metrics
    interval: 15s
    scrapeTimeout: 14s
  - port: prometheus-tls
    scheme: https
    path: /metrics/detailed
    params:
      family:
        - queue_coarse_metrics
        - queue_metrics
    interval: 15s
    scrapeTimeout: 14s
    tlsConfig:
      insecureSkipVerify: true
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: rabbitmq
  namespaceSelector:
    any: true
```

I've attempted to load one of the RabbitMQ community dashboards using the following ConfigMap:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: erlang-distribution-dashboard
  namespace: kube-prometheus
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
data:
  # https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/11352
  erlang-distribution-dashboard.json.url: https://grafana.com/api/dashboards/11352/revisions/7/download
```

However the dashboard does not appear and after tailing the grafana container logs using command:

```
kubectl logs prom-grafana-895847f4f-mbfzw  -n kube-prometheus --tail 1 --follow -c grafana
```

I saw the following error:

```
logger=provisioning.dashboard type=file name=sidecarProvider t=2023-03-24T17:26:08.554955848Z level=error msg="failed to load dashboard from " file=/tmp/dashboards/erlang-distribution-dashboard.json error="Dashboard title cannot be empty"
```

Once I connect to the container using command:

```
kubectl exec -it prom-grafana-895847f4f-mbfzw  /bin/sh -n kube-prometheus
```

and open the above file the contents is as follows:

```
{
  "code": "InvalidCredentials",
  "message": "Invalid password",
  "requestId": "4d1d0ea3-2629-44ec-9fd6-3d172d1bce1b"
}
```

If I try to download the file manually using wget:

```
wget https://grafana.com/api/dashboards/11352/revisions/7/download -O erlang-distribution-dashboard.json
```

it succeeds with correct content but after a short time it is overwritten by the above output again. It doesn't seem to be obvious where that output is coming from so any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the issue on the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) I was pointed in the direction of the values file for the stack. I therefore added all of the community dashboards to the following and passed it as values to the chart:

```
defaultRules:
  create: false
nodeExporter:
  enabled: false
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    ruleSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
    podMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
    serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
    probeSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
alertmanager:
  alertmanagerSpec:
    useExistingSecret: true
grafana:
  env:
    GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS: flant-statusmap-panel
  dashboardProviders: 
    dashboardproviders.yaml:
      apiVersion: 1
      providers:
      - name: 'default'
        orgId: 1
        folder: ''
        type: file
        disableDeletion: false
        editable: false
        options:
          path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/default
  dashboards: 
    default:
      erlang-distribution-dashboard:
        gnetId: 11352
        revision: 7
        datasource: Prometheus
      erlang-distributions-compare-dashboard:
        gnetId: 10988
        revision: 11
        datasource: Prometheus
      erlang-memory-allocators-dashboard:
        gnetId: 11350
        revision: 5
        datasource: Prometheus
      rabbitmq-overview-dashboard:
        gnetId: 10991
        revision: 12
        datasource: Prometheus
```